# Castle Windsor: how to invoke different implementation of interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, constructor-injection

I'm kinda new in using of Castle Windsor, and didn't find relevant answers.
Lets say I have some interface

```
public interface IStoreServiceCache
{
    void Put(string key, object value);
    T Get<T>(string key);
}
```

And few implementations:
Main calls that responsible for StoreServiceCache:

```
public  class StoreServiceCache : IStoreServiceCache
{
    private readonly IStoreServiceCache _cacheRef;

    public StoreServiceCache(IStoreServiceCache concreteCache)
    {
        _cacheRef = concreteCache;//Container.Instance.Resolve<IStoreServiceCache>("FileCache");//new StoreServiceFileCache());
        LoadStoreDetailData();
    }

    public void Put(string key, object value)
    {
        _cacheRef.Put(key, value);
    }

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        return _cacheRef.Get<T>(key);
    }

    private void LoadStoresDetailData()
    {
        // Read from some file and fill cache
    }
}
```

And some specific for FileCache

```
internal class StoreServiceFileCache : IStoreServiceCache
{
    private readonly FileCache cache;

    public StoreServiceFileCache()
    {
        string cacheEndPoint = "CacheEndpoint";
        string cacheAuthToken = "CacheAuthToken";
        cache = FilesCacheFactory.Get(cacheEndPoint, cacheAuthToken);
    }

    public void Put(string key, object value)
    {
        cache.Put(key.ToLower(), value);
    }

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        T result;
        cache.Get(key.ToLower(), out result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, my Windsor intsaller looks like this

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Component.For<IStoreServiceCache>().ImplementedBy<StoreServiceCache>()
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IStoreServiceCache), "FileCache")).LifestyleSingleton());
container.Register(Component.For<IStoreServiceCache>().Named("FileCache").ImplementedBy<StoreServiceFileCache>());
```

Few questions:

1. For now if I call StoreServiceCache, it will use StoreServiceFileCache inside. And what if I also want to create StoreServiceCach, that will use another concrete cache (e.g. StoreServiceWebCache). How can I configure it with Castle.
2. If I want to use some DummyCache in my unit test. So for example, I'll create DummyCache that can load data to that cache and when I'll run unit test it will use the real data.